# ElasticSearch Python Client: how to get an index name behind an alias

Tags: elasticsearch-7

I know how to get an alias if any given an index name in ElasticSearch:

```
es.indices.get_alias(indexname)
```

Is there a way to go the other way around? Something like es.indices.get_index(aliasname)? I implemented a workaround using the es.indices.get_alias for now but I am just curious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I couldn't find any API returning an alias given an index name. Like I said, I had a workaround in Python using Elasticsearch module:

```
def get_alias_behind_index(client, indexname):
    if client.indices.exists_alias(name=indexname):
        return (list(client.indices.get_alias(indexname).keys())[0])
    return None
```

Answer (score 0):

Notice that a single alias may point to multiple indexes, so I'm assuming you want all the indexes behind that alias.

The only way I know is to:

1. list all aliases metadata
2. and iterate the aliases looking for the records related to the alias you are interested

Here is how I'll do it:

```py
from opensearchpy import OpenSearch


# Get Client
# Use your own credentials and settings according to your opensearch
HOST = 'localhost'
PORT = 9200
AUTH = ('admin', 'admin')

client = OpenSearch(
    hosts=[{'host': HOST, 'port': PORT}],
    http_auth=AUTH,
    use_ssl=True,
    verify_certs=False)

def find_index_behind_alias(alias_name):
    """Find the index behind an alias.

    Parameters
    ----------
    alias_name : str
        The alias name.

    Returns
    -------
    index_names : list
        The index names behind the alias (return an empty list if the
        alias does not exist).
    """
    # 1) Get all aliases
    all_aliases = client.cat.aliases(
        name=['*'],
        format='json')

    # 2) Iterate looking for your targeted index
    alias_exist, index_names = False, []
    for alias in all_aliases:
        if alias['alias'] == alias_name:
            alias_exist = True
            index_names.append(alias['index'])
    
    if not alias_exist:
        print('Alias does not exist')
            
    return index_names

find_index_behind_alias(alias_name='my_alias_name')
```

Note:
Use the parameter `name` to restrict what the `client.cat.aliases` returns (and update the code accordingly) if you do not want to list all the aliases with the aim to optimize the execution time of that loop.